# How do Concepts differ from Interfaces?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++11, c++-concepts

How do Concepts (ie those recently dropped from the C++0x standard) differ from Interfaces in languages such as Java?

Comment: C++ doesn't have anything called Interfaces, whereas ... oh ... hang on, they're the same. But you will have to say what you mean by "Interfaces" before the question can be answered. Java interfaces? The general OOP concept of an interface? The general concept of an interface as the "I" in API?

Comment: Are not pure virtual classes interfaces just with a different name ?

Comment: Yes, didn't make that clear. Edited.

Comment: C++ has no concept of a "pure virtual class". It does have the concept of a pure virtual function.

Comment: Wait is that the live journal onebyone?

Comment: I just assumed the questioner meant that, my bad :)

Comment: @GMan. Yes, it is. But it has occurred to me that some day, some potential employer might talk to me about StackOverflow. I prefer not to give a link to my LJ to employers, at least not until I have an offer in hand :-)

Comment: @onebyone At which point I will jump in and claim to be the real onebyone! I honestly thimk people are too paranoid about using their real names here - it doesn't seem to have done Skeet any harm!

Comment: You mean onebyone is his real name? :p

Comment: lol :) Neil, is Butterworth your last name?

Comment: Yeah, I may switch to my real name at some point in the future, but doing that means people here wouldn't recognise me for a while. Maybe onebyone -> Steve (was onebyone) -> Steve. Or something. I use pseudonyms for most signups out of habit, and initially I just named myself with the OpenID I was using. Seemed logical at the time, but as it turns out I'm pretty happy for an interviewer to analyse my SO account. Less so social sites, simply because there's nothing there that "should" be relevant to employers.

Comment: I think the de-facto way of doing it is: GMan -> Nick "GMan" Gorski -> Nick Gorski. With your name, of course.

Comment: @Gman My real name is actually "Clint Throb", I chose "Neil Butterworth" as an alias because it sounds sexier.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Concepts are for compile-time polymorphism, That means parametric generic code. Interfaces are for run-time polymorphism.

You have to implement an interface as you implement a Concept. The difference is that you don't have to explicitly say that you are implementing a Concept. If the required interface is matched then no problems. In the case of interfaces, even if you implemented **all** the required functions, you have to excitability say that you are implementing it!

---

I will try to clarify my answer :)

Imagine that you are designing a container that accepts any type that has the **size** member function. We formalize the Concept and call it HasSize, of course we should define it elsewhere but this is an example no more.

```
template <class HasSize>
class Container
{
  HasSize[10]; // just an example don't take it seriously :)
 // elements MUST have size member function!
};
```

Then, Imagine we are creating an instance of our **Container** and we call it **myShapes**, Shape is a base class and it defines the **size** member function. Square and Circle are just children of it. If Shape didn't define size then an error should be produced.

```
Container<Shape> myShapes;

if(/* some condition*/)
    myShapes.add(Square());
else
    myShapes.add(Circle());
```

I hope you see that Shape can be checked against **HasSize** at *compile time*, there is no reason to do the checking at run-time. Unlike the elements of **myShapes**, we could define a function that manipulates them :

```
void doSomething(Shape* shape)
{
    if(/* shape is a Circle*/)
        // cast then do something with the circle.
    else if( /* shape is a Square */)
        // cast then do something with the square.
}
```

In this function, you can't know what will be passed till run-time a Circle or a Square!

They are two tools for a similar job, though Interface-or whatever you call them- can do almost the same job of Concepts at run-time but you lose all benefits of compile-time checking and optimization!

Comment: Ya, this answer seems fine to me. +1

Comment: I was the downvoter. AraK has completely re-edited his answer, but the re-edit doesn't show up because of the vagaries of SO.

Comment: Sorry I was writing in hurry I didn't finish my post first time :(

Comment: @AraK, I changed "excitability" to "explicitly" - is this what you mean? (it didn't make sense before)

Comment: Why do you say that interfaces are for run-time polymorphism? Interface constraints are checked at compile time. Are you referring to the vtable lookups? Additionally, your `doSomething` function doesn't really show how interfaces and concepts differ and seems kind of irrelevant. How would you accomplish `doSomething` differently with concepts? And why don't you use polymorphism instead of if-else chains and casts?

Answer (score 7):

Concepts are likes types (classes) for templates: it's for the generic programming side of the language only.

In that way, it's not meant to replace the interface classes (assuming you mean abstract classes or other C++ equivalent implementation of C# or Java Interfaces)  as it's only meant to check types used in template parameters to match specific requirements. 
The type check is only done at compile time like all the template code generation and whereas interface classes have an impact on runtime execution.

Answer (score 3):

Concepts are implicit interfaces. In C# or Java a class must explicitly implement an interface, whereas in C++ a class is part of a concept merely as long as it meets the concept's constraints.

The reason you will see concepts in C++ and not in Java or C# is because C++ doesn't really have "interfaces". Instead, you can simulate an interface by using multiple inheritance and abstract, memberless base classes. These are somewhat of a hack and can be a headache to work with (e.g. virtual inheritance and [The Diamond Problem](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/diamond-problem/)). Interfaces play a critical role in OOP and polymorphism, and that role has not been adequately fulfilled in C++ so far. Concepts are the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's more or less a difference in the point of view. While an interface (as in C#) is specified similar to a base class, a concept can also be matched automatically (similar to duck-typing in Python). It is still unclear to which level C++ is going to support automatic concept matching, which is one of the reasons why they dropped it.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, as per my understanding.

- **Concept** is a constraint on the template parameter of a Type (i.e., class or struct) or a Method
- **Interfaces** is a contract that Type (i.e., class Or struct) has to implement.