# Are C++ "Concepts" same as ObjectiveC "protocols" and Java "Interfaces"?

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, c++11

In what ways C++ "Concepts" are better or worse than ObjC Protocols and Java Interfaces?

Answer (score 5):

First of all this answer is better than mine:
[How do Concepts differ from Interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183210/how-do-concepts-differ-from-interfaces?rq=1)

Anyway, my original before I checked for dups:

This is a bit like asking if a loaf of bread is better or worse than a speedboat.

C++ "Concepts" apply to constraints on **type parameters** used in generically-typed functions and classes (**templates**).

Protocols and Interfaces specify the methods that an adopting/implementing class (generic or otherwise) must implement.

C++ already has an analog to protocols and interfaces, which are classes that consist of nothing but pure virtual functions:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Abstract_classes_and_pure_virtual_functions

I can see the source of the confusion; at the most abstract level, concepts and interfaces and protocols all have to do with specifying behavior while avoiding implementation; but where they are used in the language is fundamentally different so you can't make a real comparison.

Also, your question badly needs rewriting so that it has a real answer rather than editorializing or hand-waving or cattle-herding or sheep breeding, whatever it is that I'm doing.

Also, *concepts* are quite early in the pipeline, being at proposed stage of the C++ standard only: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4361.pdf

"Right now it's only a notion, but I think I can get the money to make it into a concept, and later turn it into an idea." -- *Annie Hall*